# drawing shapes from a vector filled with classes

Tags: c++, vector, sfml

I am trying to draw a shape that I define in a class.
I put this class in a vector and made a for loop where I go trough the vector and call its draw function.
however I only draw one of the many shapes of the class I add to the vector.
And in my game loop I use the for loop

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

int main(){
RenderWindow window{ { 800, 600}, "game" };

window.setFramerateLimit(60);

 vector<Block> blocks;
for (int iX = 0; iX < 10; iX++)
    for (int iY = 0; iY < 10; iY++)
        blocks.emplace_back(iX * 50, iY * 50);

while(true){
for (auto& Block : blocks) {
        Block.Draw(window);
    }


}
```

the class that gets called looks like this.

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
using namespace std;
using namespace sf;   


RectangleShape blockshape;


Block::Block(float mX,float mY)
    {
        blockshape.setPosition(mX, mY);

        blockWidht = 30.f;
        blockHeight = 60.f;
        blockshape.setSize({ blockWidht,blockHeight });
        blockshape.setFillColor(Color::Green);
        blockshape.setOrigin(blockWidht / 2.f, blockHeight / 2.f);

        x = blockshape.getPosition().x;
        y = blockshape.getPosition().y;

    }
     void Block::Draw(RenderWindow& window) {
        window.draw(blockshape);
    }
```

I  checked how full my vector was and it did show that there was more then of my block class in it

I hope this is enough information to answer my question.

Comment: `blocks.emplace_back(*new Block((iX ) * 30, (iY + 3) * 60));`?? This is not only a memory leak, it's the opposite of how you should be using `emplace_back`

Comment: In what other way should I be using it?

Comment: The entire point of `emplace_back` is that it constructs the object *in-place* - you only pass it the constructor arguments, so in your case it would probably be `blocks.emplace_back((iX ) * 30, (iY + 3) * 60);`

Comment: Also you need to provide a proper [mcve] - so far it's unclear what `blockshape` is or how it is initialized

Comment: I edited my post and hope its better like this, thanks for pointing me to that page! however my problem persists still.

Comment: This still isn't enough to reproduce the issue. Please include a minimal definition of `Block` that is required to have code that can be compiled

Comment: I update my code once again, sorry for the imcomplete code on my earlier versions, I hope this  suffices.

Comment: `RectangleShape blockshape;` defines a *global* variable, that each new instance of your class overwrites - you are simply drawing the exact same shape every time you call `Draw` - `RectangleShape blockshape;` should be a member of `Block`

Comment: Thanks for the tip! that indeed seems to be the problem, I'll look for a way to  fix my problem and still be able to use my draw function. after that I'll update my post.